# ls,sudo commands not found (shell commands)

Tags: bash, shell, path

I tried to install laravel Framework in my mac OSX 10 .And I ended  modifying my `~/.bash_profile` to add the laravel command. laravel command seems to work normally .But another problem came out . ls ,sudo ...and other shell commands does not work .

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

My `bash.profile` file  contains the two links

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

check in ~/.bash_profile if this PATHs exist

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

your complete line should looks like this

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

reboot needed.

Comment: Thanks men , It returned to normal . I just formatted the two files bash_profile and  bashrc . for Laravel i added the line alias laravel='~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel'

Answer (score 0):

The binaries for the above mentioned utilities for debian distribution are usually in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` directory. Of course exporting path won't help if the binaries are not there.

There could be one simple approach to it -

- Check for the location of binaries and then export the path in the bash_profile or .bashrc.
- Run the bashrc script (`. ~/.bashrc`) following you may not require a reboot.